# Pickle Lazy Learners

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle, knn

Does Pickle save training data for lazy learners like KNeighboursClassifier form sci-kit ? If so, can we access this data from a pickle object ? (Asking for data privacy issues)*

Eg:

```
knn.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)

saved_model = pickle.dumps(knn)

knn_from_pickle = pickle.loads(saved_model)

#This function works after directly loading pickled object (saved_model) and gives correct and logical output
knn_from_pickle.predict(Xtest)
```

Does knn_from_pickle or saved_model variables contain `Xtrain` data? Since Knn is a lazy learner and requires distance calculations, when new data arrives with respect to training data `Xtrain`. When I printed `knn_from_pickle` I was just displayed hyperparameters passed to KNeighboursClassifier algorithm.

As I observed that for a 65KB file of data (Xtrain) with all data transformations and taking this entire data for training, when the knn model was fit and serialized like so:

```
saved_model = pickle.dumps(knn)
sys.getsizeof(saved_model)
```

space occupied was **238744 bytes**

Whereas space occupied for pickled objects of other algorithms like Gaussian Naive Bayes was:

```
saved_model = pickle.dumps(gnb)
sys.getsizeof(saved_model)
```

space occupied was **6074  bytes** and for heavy algorithms like Random Forest:

```
saved_model = pickle.dumps(rf)
sys.getsizeof(saved_model)
```

space occupied was **48863 bytes**

Seeing this much space difference between KNN and other algorithm's pickled objects, pickle must be storing training data somehow for KNN. If yes, how to access it? Or how is knn stored in pickle, if no then how is unpickled object (knn_from_pickle) using predict without fit and giving correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the data is saved in a private attribute, but since python doesn't actually respect private methods/attributes, you'd need to keep privacy concerns in mind before publicizing the fitted model.

For `KNeighborsClassifier`, the attribute is `_fit_X` (at time of writing; being a private attribute, the developers wouldn't think much of changing that).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I accessed all the data I had fitted the model with. I wanted to ask how can I find such attributes that store data for other lazy learner models or for encoders like One Hot Encoder or Standard Scaler, after they fit the data ?

Comment: Some of them are public attributes, so the sklearn API documentation is quick and easy.  For private attributes like `KNeighborsClassifier`, you'll have to scan the source code (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe used in training can indeed be retrieved and parsed into a new Pandas dataframe using this code:

```html
import pickle
import pandas as pd

loaded_model = pickle.load(open('knnpickle_file', 'rb'))
data = pd.DataFrame(loaded_model._fit_X, columns=loaded_model.feature_names_in_)
```