# Can I access the dataset saved in a scikit-learn NearestNeighbors model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

When fitting a sklearn NearestNeighbors model on a dataset, the model holds that data as its state. In the words of sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbors):

> Neighbors-based methods are known as non-generalizing machine learning methods, since they simply “remember” all of its training data (possibly transformed into a fast indexing structure such as a Ball Tree or KD Tree).

Is it possible to access the data structure that is preserved inside a model once it's been fit? Or is it necessary to have access to the original training data outside of the model? It seems like this would be an inefficient use of memory/space, since anything you would want to query would already be preserved inside the model. Can't I just grab the NumPy array from an index value instead of holding onto a big NumPy array at all times?

Comment: What do you need "access to the original training data outside of the model" for?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62761472/10495893

Comment: @BenReiniger before I knew of "_fit_X", I thought I needed to store the same dataset that the model was trained on in my project in order to make queries. This seemed redundant, since the model just has all of that information already. Thanks for sending the related thread.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like calling `_fit_X` on your model instance will return your training data, and you can index from there.